# In numpy how to add a number to some consecutive elements of an array?

Tags: numpy

Suppose I start with a numpy array as follows.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

I then want to add a 3 to elements starting at 2 and to the end. The resulting array would look as follows.

```
[1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

The best I can figure is to create the following array and add them.

```
[0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Why not just `arr[2:] += 3`

Comment: @user3483203 That's perfect, if you post that as an answer I will accept it.